# CSS link not added to master page

Tags: css, cssregistration

I have a custom CSS file is in 14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\MyStuff folder. Masterpage markup contains the following:

```
<SharePoint:CssLink runat="server" Version="4"/>
<SharePoint:Theme runat="server"/>
<SharePoint:ULSClientConfig runat="server"/>
<SharePoint:CssRegistration runat="server" Name="/_layouts/MyStuff/my_style.css" After="corev4.css"/>
```

The problem is that CSS links are not added to the page at all as if CssLink gets rendered to nothing. At the same time, the CSS is accessible via http://mysite/_layouts/MyStuff/my_style.css. Moreover, I have several sripts in the same folder linked to master page like this:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink runat="server" Name="/_layouts/MyStuff/thescript.js" />
```

and this works just fine. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your site running in 2007 compatibility mode by chance?  If so, that `Version="4"` is what is preventing it from rendering as the page itself is trying to render as `Version="3"` and would ignore all version 4 controls.

Comment: Do you need the `Version="4"`? I don't have that at all in mine and it loads the CSS just fine.